# Validating Login and Password

Tags: python

```
def IsValidLogin(login_name):
  lognum = 0
  login = 0

  if len(login_name) >= 8:
    lognum == True
  elif len(login_name) < 8:
    lognum == False


  for chr in login_name:
    if chr.isalnum() == True:
        login == True
    else:
        login == False

  if (login == True) and (lognum == True):
    IsValidLogin  == True
  else:
    IsValidLogin == False

  if IsValidLogin == True:
    print('Login Accepted')
  else:
    print('Login Failed')

  return lognum, login


login_name = input('Please enter your Login: ')
lognum, login = IsValidLogin(login_name)

def IsValidPassword(password):
  pass_char = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+']

  pass_len = 0
  pass_num = 0
  spec_char = 0

  for chr in password:
    if len(password) >= 8:
        pass_len == True
    elif len(password) < 8:
        pass_len == False

  for chr in password:
    if chr.isdigit() == True:
        pass_num == True
    elif chr.isdigit() == False:
        pass_num == False

  for chr in password:
    if password == pass_char:
        spec_char == True
    elif password != pass_char:
        spec_char == False

  if (pass_len == True) and (spec_char == True):
    IsValidPassword == True
  else:
    IsValidPassword == False

  if IsValidPassword == True:
    print('Password Accepted')
  else:
    print('Password Failed')

  return pass_len, pass_num, spec_char 

password = input('Please enter your password: ')
pass_len, pass_num, spec_char = IsValidPassword(password)
```

The login needs to be at least 8 characters long and can only contain letters and numbers.

The password has to be at least 8 characters long, have at least one number, and one special character.

Program runs, but both return false.

Wondering what I am doing wrong. Please keep in mind I am very new into Python.

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
  if len(login_name) >= 8:
    lognum == True
  elif len(login_name) < 8:
    lognum == False
```

seem wrong. It seems like you're trying to assign to `lognum` but instead you are comparing `lognum` to `True` and `False`. `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison. Similar for:

```
if chr.isalnum() == True:
    login == True
else:
    login == False
```

and

```
  if (login == True) and (lognum == True):
    IsValidLogin  == True
  else:
    IsValidLogin == False
```

and several other places outside the function.

Just change the appropriate `==` to `=` and it should work.

You also have a logic problem in the password part even with this change: this will always return false, because it only checks the last character, which cannot be both a number and a special character.

```
  for chr in password:
    if chr.isdigit() == True:
        pass_num = True
    elif chr.isdigit() == False:
        pass_num = False #On the last pass through, this overwrites the previous value

  for chr in password:
    if password == pass_char:
        spec_char = True
    elif password != pass_char:
        spec_char = False #On the last pass through, this overwrites the previous value
```

Change `elif password != pass_char:` to `elif not spec_char:` and `elif chr.is_digit():` to `elif not pass_num:` to keep this from being overwritten.